# Is getmypid() safe to uniquely identify an Apache process running PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, multiprocessing

As far as I understand it, different processes have different PIDs, but different threads in a given process all share the same PID, but differ by their TID.

I'm using Apache + PHP in my application, and AFAIK, there's no such thing as a multi-threaded PHP. So, is it safe to say that [getmypid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php) will uniquely identify a running Apache+PHP process at a point in time?

The idea is to implement an application-level lock in the database, where a process would try to update a record with its PID, to assign a resource to itself.